# Error con foreach y producto cartesiano

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código:

```
$CArticulos = Consulta_Dinamica("Array","*","Articulos","`borrado` != 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    if ($CArticulos) { //si existen Datos en la base de datos

foreach($CArticulos as $DArticulos) {

if (isset($DArticulos['talla'])) { $taLlas = explode(",", $DArticulos['talla']); } else { $tallas=""; }
if (isset($DArticulos['color'])) { $coLores = explode(",", $DArticulos['color']); } else { $colores=""; }

$UpTallicolor = CartesianProduct(array('tallas'=> $taLlas, 'color'=> $coLores));
foreach($UpTallicolor as $DUptallicolor) {
    $CExisteArt = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Test","`que` = 'Codigo' AND `idcosa` = '".$DArticulos["id"]."' AND `Dc1`='".$DUptallicolor['tallas']."' AND `Dc2`='".$DUptallicolor['color']."' ");
    if ($CExisteArt) { echo "existe"; } else { echo "no existe";
        $CCodEan = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Configuraciones","`Conf_que` = 'Codigos' AND `Conf1` = '".$_SESSION['Empresa_Pais']."' ");
        $Eanmin = $CCodEan["Conf2"].$CCodEan["Conf3"].$CCodEan["Conf4"]; $Eanmax = $CCodEan["Conf2"].$CCodEan["Conf3"].$CCodEan["Conf5"];

        $CeanLibre = "SELECT MIN(t1.`Dc3`)+1 as prox_ean_libre FROM `Test` t1 LEFT JOIN `Test` t2 ON t2.`Dc3`=(t1.`Dc3`)+1 AND t2.`Dc3` BETWEEN '".$Eanmin."' AND '".$Eanmax."' WHERE t1.`Dc3` BETWEEN '".$Eanmin."' AND '".$Eanmax."' AND t2.`Dc3` IS NULL"; //miramos de nuevo el ultimo codigo por si aca
        $REanLibre = mysqli_query($Conectar ,$CeanLibre); $DEanLibre=mysqli_fetch_array($REanLibre);
        if (empty($DEanLibre["prox_ean_libre"])) { $Eanlibre = $Eanmin; } else { $Eanlibre = $DEanLibre["prox_ean_libre"]; }
        $UpdTallicolor = Insertar_Datos("Test" , "`que`,`idcosa`,`Dc1`,`Dc2`,`Dc3`" , "'Codigo','".$DArticulos["id"]."','".$DUptallicolor['tallas']."','".$DUptallicolor['color']."','".$Eanlibre."' "); } //si no existe ese articulo en los codigos
        mysqli_free_result($REanLibre);
} //cierro el foreach
```

Lo que hace es leer la tabla articulos de mysql, genera un array con tallas y otro con colores que ejecuta otro loop con un producto cartesiano para asignar códigos ean a cada producto cartesiano, en el que miro cual está libre previamente. El caso es que si tiene pocos registros, funciona bien, pero en el momento que hay bastantes (unos 100) es lento hasta el punto que da error de tiempo de espera y no guarda nada.

¿Hay alguna forma de optimizarlo o hacer que se ejecute poco a poco (con cada loop que guarde en mysql )?

el código de generar el producto cartesiano es este:

```
function CartesianProduct($sets) {
    $cartesian = array();
    foreach ($sets as $key => $set) { if (empty($set)) { continue; } // Si un grupo esta vació no afecta el producto cartesiano
    if (empty($cartesian)) { $cartesian[] = array(); }// Si esta vacio agregamos el primer grupo
    $subset = array();
    foreach ($cartesian as $product) {
        foreach($set as $value) {
            $product[$key] = $value;
            $subset[] = $product;
        }
    }
$cartesian = $subset;
    }
return $cartesian;
}
```

el array que me genera el producto cartesiano de un solo articulo es este:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 250 ) [1] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 252 ) [2] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 185 ) [3] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 158 ) [4] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 183 ) [5] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 106 ) [6] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 198 ) [7] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 181 ) [8] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 72 ) [9] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 178 ) [10] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 184 ) [11] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 180 ) [12] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 196 ) [13] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 147 ) [14] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 116 ) [15] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 166 ) [16] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 165 ) [17] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 179 ) [18] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 151 ) [19] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 197 ) [20] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 195 ) [21] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 [color] => 177 ) [22] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 250 ) [23] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 252 ) [24] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 185 ) [25] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 158 ) [26] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 183 ) [27] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 106 ) [28] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 198 ) [29] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 181 ) [30] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 72 ) [31] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 178 ) [32] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 184 ) [33] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 180 ) [34] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 196 ) [35] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 147 ) [36] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 116 ) [37] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 166 ) [38] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 165 ) [39] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 179 ) [40] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 151 ) [41] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 197 ) [42] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 195 ) [43] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 [color] => 177 ) [44] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 250 ) [45] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 252 ) [46] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 185 ) [47] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 158 ) [48] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 183 ) [49] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 106 ) [50] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 198 ) [51] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 181 ) [52] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 72 ) [53] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 178 ) [54] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 184 ) [55] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 180 ) [56] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 196 ) [57] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 147 ) [58] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 116 ) [59] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 166 ) [60] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 165 ) [61] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 179 ) [62] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 151 ) [63] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 197 ) [64] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 195 ) [65] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 [color] => 177 ) [66] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 250 ) [67] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 252 ) [68] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 185 ) [69] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 158 ) [70] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 183 ) [71] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 106 ) [72] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 198 ) [73] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 181 ) [74] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 72 ) [75] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 178 ) [76] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 184 ) [77] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 180 ) [78] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 196 ) [79] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 147 ) [80] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 116 ) [81] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 166 ) [82] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 165 ) [83] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 179 ) [84] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 151 ) [85] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 197 ) [86] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 195 ) [87] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 [color] => 177 ) [88] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 250 ) [89] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 252 ) [90] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 185 ) [91] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 158 ) [92] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 183 ) [93] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 106 ) [94] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 198 ) [95] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 181 ) [96] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 72 ) [97] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 178 ) [98] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 184 ) [99] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 180 ) [100] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 196 ) [101] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 147 ) [102] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 116 ) [103] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 166 ) [104] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 165 ) [105] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 179 ) [106] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 151 ) [107] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 197 ) [108] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 195 ) [109] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 [color] => 177 ) [110] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 250 ) [111] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 252 ) [112] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 185 ) [113] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 158 ) [114] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 183 ) [115] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 106 ) [116] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 198 ) [117] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 181 ) [118] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 72 ) [119] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 178 ) [120] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 184 ) [121] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 180 ) [122] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 196 ) [123] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 147 ) [124] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 116 ) [125] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 166 ) [126] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 165 ) [127] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 179 ) [128] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 151 ) [129] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 197 ) [130] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 195 ) [131] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 [color] => 177 ) [132] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 250 ) [133] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 252 ) [134] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 185 ) [135] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 158 ) [136] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 183 ) [137] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 106 ) [138] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 198 ) [139] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 181 ) [140] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 72 ) [141] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 178 ) [142] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 184 ) [143] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 180 ) [144] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 196 ) [145] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 147 ) [146] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 116 ) [147] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 166 ) [148] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 165 ) [149] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 179 ) [150] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 151 ) [151] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 197 ) [152] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 195 ) [153] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 [color] => 177 ) [154] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 250 ) [155] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 252 ) [156] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 185 ) [157] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 158 ) [158] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 183 ) [159] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 106 ) [160] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 198 ) [161] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 181 ) [162] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 72 ) [163] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 178 ) [164] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 184 ) [165] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 180 ) [166] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 196 ) [167] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 147 ) [168] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 116 ) [169] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 166 ) [170] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 165 ) [171] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 179 ) [172] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 151 ) [173] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 197 ) [174] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 195 ) [175] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 177 ) )
```

el array que genera el codigo de la respuesta es este:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [tallas] => 60 ) [1] => Array ( [tallas] => 61 ) [2] => Array ( [tallas] => 62 ) [3] => Array ( [tallas] => 63 ) [4] => Array ( [tallas] => 64 ) [5] => Array ( [tallas] => 65 ) [6] => Array ( [tallas] => 66 ) [7] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 ) [8] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 250 ) [9] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 252 ) [10] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 185 ) [11] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 158 ) [12] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 183 ) [13] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 106 ) [14] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 198 ) [15] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 181 ) [16] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 72 ) [17] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 178 ) [18] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 184 ) [19] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 180 ) [20] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 196 ) [21] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 147 ) [22] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 116 ) [23] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 166 ) [24] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 165 ) [25] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 179 ) [26] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 151 ) [27] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 197 ) [28] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 195 ) [29] => Array ( [tallas] => 67 [color] => 177 ) )
```

Comment: He visto que haces consultas contra la BD dentro de un *foreach*, los accesos a la base de datos son costosos y de ahí viene tu problema.

Comment: hola @Orici he sacado el de $CCodEan que es el único que puede ser consultado una sola vez, pero el resto creo que son necesarios

Comment: ¿Consultas varias y de varios tipos `SELECT` ... `INSERT`... dentro de un bucle `for`?  Me parece que necesitas replantear la lógica del funcionamiento de tu código y quizá la lógica de la base de datos, de forma que obtengas mediante una sola consulta, mediante `JOIN` y filtros `WHERE` adecuados, los datos que necesitas. Una vez obtenidos los datos haces las comparaciones de lugar.

Comment: @A.Cedano varios tipos de insert dentro del bucle? Que yo sepa solo hay uno que está condicionado a si existe ya o no. Si se pueden poner condiciones en mysql estaría encantado de no usar un bucle. Aunque para recorrer un producto cartesiano necesito si o si un bucle.

Comment: No dije varios tipos de INSERT sino varios tipos de consultas: o sea, consultas mezcladas (SELECT e INSERT) dentro de un bucle. La práctica es mala ya con un solo tipo de  consulta. Y si son dos tipos, peor aún. Intuyo que hay en alguna parte uno o varios errores de lógica en la forma en que estás concibiendo tu programa. Si explicas mejor como están diseñadas tus tablas y el resultado que quieres obtener podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Estaba mirando con más detenimiento tu código. Puede que tengas múltiples errores en la lógica del programa, ya sin meternos en diseño de la BD.

Prueba a cambiar tu función *CartesianProduct* por esta otra de momento, a ver si te sigue funcionando:

```
function CartesianProduct( $arr_sets ) {

    if ( ! $arr_sets || ! is_array( $arr_sets ))
        return FALSE;


    $product   = array();
    $cartesian = array();
    foreach ( $arr_sets as $key => $set ) {

        if ( $set && is_array( $set )) { 

            foreach( $set as $value ) {

                $product[ $key ] = $value;
                $cartesian[] = $product;
            }
        }
    }


    return $cartesian;
}
```

**==================

Añado contenido:**

Es más pequeño y cambia la forma de interpretarlo, lo que 
no se si tiene todos los datos. No puedo probarlo. Te 
explicare en pasos lo que cambie.

```
/*** Código original ***/
function CartesianProduct( $arr_sets ) {

    $cartesian = array();
    foreach ( $arr_sets as $key => $set ) { 

        if ( empty( $set )) { 
            continue; 
        } // Si un grupo esta vació no afecta el producto cartesiano

        if ( empty( $cartesian )) { 
            $cartesian[] = array(); 
        }// Si esta vacio agregamos el primer grupo

        $subset = array();
        foreach ( $cartesian as $product ) {

            foreach( $set as $value ) {

                $product[ $key ] = $value;
                $subset[] = $product;
            }
        }

        $cartesian = $subset;
    }

    return $cartesian;
}


/**
 * 1. Esto generaría el mismo array que tu código
 * 
 * Inicializo todos los arrays que vamos a utilizar fuera del foreach principal
 * Elimino tus dos primeros bloques condicionales:
 *   "if (empty($set)) { continue; }" lo sustituyo incluyendo todo en el condicional:
 *   "if ( $set && is_array( $set )) { ... }" incluyendo el código subsiguiente 
 *   dentro "if (empty($cartesian)) { $cartesian[] = array(); }" lo sustituyo por 
 *   
 *   "$cartesian[] = array();" antes del foreach, entiendo que esto se hace en
 *   la primera iteración del foreach porque $cartesian, recien declarado es un 
 *   array vacio siempre
 * 
 */
function CartesianProduct( $arr_sets ) {

    if ( ! $arr_sets || ! is_array( $arr_sets ))
        return FALSE;

    $cartesian = array();
    $subset    = array();
    $cartesian[] = array();
    foreach ($arr_sets as $key => $set) {

        if ( $set && is_array( $set )) {

            foreach ($cartesian as $product) {

                foreach($set as $value) {

                    $product[$key] = $value;
                    $subset[] = $product;
                }
            }

            $cartesian = $subset; 
        }
    }


    return $cartesian;
}

/**
 * 2. Mismo código, con una clausula de salvaguarda al comienzo y comentarios. La salida debería seguir siendo la misma que tienes
 * 
 */
function CartesianProduct( $arr_sets ) {

    /**
     * Clausula de salvaguarda
     * 
     * Evita error si la función no recibe un array y que se siga ejecutando 
     * el resto del código, evitando añadir un nivel de indentado
     */
    if ( ! $arr_sets || ! is_array( $arr_sets ))
        return FALSE;

    /**
     * Inicializa los arrays que se usarán
     *
     */
    $cartesian = array();
    $subset    = array();
    $cartesian[] = array();
    foreach ( $arr_sets as $key => $set ) {

        //Este condicional actua como la clausula de salvaguarda, pero no
        //finaliza la ejcución ni evita un nivel de indentado, incluye todo 
        //lo que se va a enecutar en la interacción en su interior
        if ( $set && is_array( $set )) {

            foreach ($cartesian as $product) {

                foreach($set as $value) {

                    $product[$key] = $value;
                    $subset[] = $product;
                }
            }

            $cartesian = $subset; 
        }
    }


    return $cartesian;
}

/**
 * 3. Simplificando. Esto cambia la salida
 * 
 * Pongo sólo la parte de código que queda por cambiar
 */
$cartesian = array();
$subset    = array();
//$cartesian[] = array();
foreach ( $arr_sets as $key => $set ) {

    //Este condicional actua como la clausula de salvaguarda, pero no
    //finaliza la ejcución ni evita un nivel de indentado, incluye todo 
    //lo que se va a enecutar en la interacción en su interior
    if ( $set && is_array( $set )) {

        /**
         * Este foreach sobra, se debería ejecutar una sola vez, solo 
         * tiene un array vacio en la primera posición
         * 
         * Una declaración previa de "$product = array();" reemplazaría 
         * a "$cartesian[] = array();" y permite eliminar este "foreach"
         */
        //foreach ($cartesian as $product) {

            foreach( $set as $value ) {

                $product[ $key ] = $value;
                $subset[] = $product;
            }
        //}

        $cartesian = $subset; 
    }
}

/**
 * 4. Simplificando. Esto cambia la salida
 * 
 * Pongo sólo la parte de código que queda por cambiar
 * 
 * El array "subset" ya no es necesario, empleo a "cartesian" en su lugar
 */
$cartesian = array();
$product   = array();
foreach ( $arr_sets as $key => $set ) {

    if ( $set && is_array( $set )) {

        foreach( $set as $value ) {

            $product[ $key ] = $value;
            $cartesian[] = $product;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: voy... de todos modos parece que el problema lo tengo al consultar el codigo mínimo

Comment: el array que genera es totalmente diferente... es mucho mas pequeño este. pongo los dos en mi pregunta. pero me da la sensación que no salen colores en todas las tallas.

Comment: Lo he editado. Explique como pude lo que hice. Ahora bien, viendo los datos que manejas, y la complejidad del código, ¿no sería mejor una salida tipo:

array(
    100 => [ 68, 69, 72 ],
    103 => [ 68, 69, 72 ],
    205 => [ 68, 69, 70, 71, 72 ],
    343 => [ 68, 69, 72, 73 ]
)

donde los índices sean los colores y los arrays las tallas que hay para esos colores?
¿Puedes incluir el array de entrada a la función?

Comment: Y hacer ese array y pasar del producto cartesiano como tal? Pues es otra opción... pero entonces serían dos bucles ¿no? Uno que recorra las tallas y dentro de ese otro que recorra los colores...

Comment: @Killpe a la hora de mostrarlos si quieres obtener todo si, aunque igual es mas lógico usar tallas para los indices y guardar colores disponibles. El tema es reducir la complejidad al obtener esos datos que es mucha.